# R - Data frame manipulation without a for loop

Tags: r

I want to read a dataframe read if the first column is T or F and depending on this I will add a new entry to a new column in the matrix using data from the second column.

```
If z[,1] == true set z[,4] to 2*z[,2]
else set z[,4] to z[,2]
```

Set if the row in column 1 is true, set the new entry to 2 times the second column, other wise just set it to the value of the second column at that index

Lets create z:

```
set.seed(4)
z <- data.frame(first=c(T, F, F, T, F), second=sample(-2:2),
                third=letters[5:1], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
z
```

here is my for loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(z)){
  if(z$first == TRUE){
    z$newVar2 <- 2*z$second
  }
  else{
    z$newVar2 <- z$second
  }
}
```

Here is without a for loop:

```
z$newVar<-ifelse(z$first==TRUE, 2*z$second, z$second)
```

Is there a way to do this with apply? Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: `ifelse` is already the right way to do this. You don't need the `==TRUE`, though, as it's already Boolean.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a for loop?

Comment: @Shekeine I don't particularly want to avoid it, just wanted to know if there was another more concise way.

Comment: aaah, actually, looking at ur question again, I would skip the apply as well, put my data in a data.table and all the stuff I want done in a function then run that function on the data.table...Would be super fast, super efficient..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not what you asked exactly but if working with a matrix data structure, you might as well explore `data.table` way of going about it:

```
#Make data.table
setDT(z)
setkey(z)

#Write function to do all the stuff
myfun <- function(first, second){ifelse(first, 2*second, second)}

#Do stuff
z[, newvar2:=myfun(first, second)]

#Printing z
   first second third newvar2
1: FALSE     -2     d      -2
2: FALSE     -1     a      -1
3: FALSE      1     c       1
4:  TRUE      0     e       0
5:  TRUE      2     b       4
```

Comment: interesting, I have never seen this before.

Comment: check [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) and [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) for a more complete walk-through of data.tables. Be sure to understand the `assignment  by reference` and `key` paradigms coz that's where data.tables really shine. If you work with big data, only data.tables will do..

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table` in a more efficient way still without defining a function, by making use of the fact that `TRUE == 1`

```
## use set.seed because we are sampling
set.seed(123)
z <- data.frame(first=c(T, F, F, T, F), 
                second=sample(-2:2),
                third=letters[5:1], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(data.table)

setDT(z)[, newvar2 := (first + 1) * second]
z

#     first second third newvar2
# 1:  TRUE     -1     e      -2
# 2: FALSE      1     d       1
# 3: FALSE      2     c       2
# 4:  TRUE      0     b       0
# 5: FALSE     -2     a      -2
```